# Weak convergence in $L^2$

Tags: hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, limsup-and-liminf

I'm studying weak convergence in $L^p$ space and I got trouble in understanding the following identity:

> If $u_n \rightharpoonup  u$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, then
>   $$ \|u \|^2 + \limsup_{n \to \infty} \| u_n - u \|^2 = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \|u_n\|^2 .$$

Can anyone show me how we get that one?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

First we have
$$
\| u_n-u \|^2 = \langle u_n-u, u_n-u \rangle = \|u_n\|^2 + \|u\|^2 - 2 \Re \langle u_n, u \rangle,
$$
where $\Re$ denotes the real part.

Now, since $u_n \rightharpoonup u,$ for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ such that $|\langle u_n, u \rangle - \langle u, u \rangle| < \epsilon$ whenever $n>N.$ Therefore $\langle u_n, u \rangle = \|u\|^2 + \delta,$ where $|\delta|<\epsilon.$ Thus,
$$
\| u_n-u \|^2 = \|u_n\|^2 + \|u\|^2 - 2 \Re (\|u\|^2 + \delta)
= \|u_n\|^2 - \|u\|^2 - 2 \Re\delta
$$
i.e.
$$
\|u\|^2 + \| u_n-u \|^2 = \|u_n\|^2 - 2 \Re\delta
$$

Taking limits as $n \to \infty$ we end up with
$$
\|u\|^2 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \| u_n-u \|^2 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \|u_n\|^2
$$
and therefore also
$$
\|u\|^2 + \limsup_{n\to\infty} \| u_n-u \|^2 = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \|u_n\|^2
$$

I'm not sure if I'm missing something. As you can see I get a stronger result with ordinary limits, not just limit superior.

Comment: $\lim\|u_n\|^2$ might not exist (for example if $u_n$ is the indicator function $1_{[n,n+1]}$ for even $n$ and zero otherwise, then $u_n\rightharpoonup 0$ but $\lim\|u_n\|^2$ doesn't exist)

Comment: Ah, thank you! But going from $\|u\|^2 + \| u_n-u \|^2 = \|u_n\|^2 - 2 \Re\delta$ to $\|u\|^2 + \limsup_{n\to\infty} \| u_n-u \|^2 = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \|u_n\|^2$ is okay?

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if the statememt is true for $p \neq 2$.

Comment: @md2perpe: yeah the rest is fine. You could also say $\|u_n\|^2-\|u_n-u\|^2\to \|u\|^2.$

Comment: @MarryMag. When $p \neq 2$ we don't have $\|u\|^2 = \langle u, u \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

> If $\left(a_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$, $\left(b_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ and $\left(\delta_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ are sequences of real numbers such that $a_n=b_n+\delta_n$ and $\delta_n\to 0$, then $\limsup_{n\to +\infty} a_n=\limsup_{n\to +\infty} b_n$.

Apply this to $a_n:=\left\lVert u_n-u\right\rVert_2$, $b_n:=\left\lVert u_n-u\right\rVert_2+\left\lVert u\right\rVert_2$ and $\delta_n:=-2\left\langle u_n,u\right\rangle$.

Comment: I think that you should have $\delta_n:=-2 \Re \left\langle u_n,u\right\rangle$.